# How can I change table navbar with CSS in an extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a Chrome extension for my university and I have done most of the things I want to do but I am having difficulty with one thing is that whenever I try to select the first `<table>` tag which is the navbar in this [link](https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp) I can't seem to hide it and then add my custom navbar using CSS.

Here is my code (I have included random createtextnode that I want to add to give a sense for what I want do or I am trying to do):

### CSS

```css
table:nth-child(1)
{
    display:none;
}
```

### JavaScript

```js
var note = document.getElementsByName('stud_login')[0];
var par = document.createElement("div");
var tag = document.createElement("a");
var t1 = document.createTextNode(" Hello! Please try to refresh page again if the verification is not filled properly.");
var t2 = document.createTextNode("Click here");
var t3 = document.createTextNode(" Any suggestions? ");
var br = document.createElement("br");

par.setAttribute("class", "info-msg"); 

par.appendChild(t1);
tag.setAttribute("href", "http://goo.gl/forms/QI8gPMfKML");
tag.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
tag.setAttribute("id", "rahultag");
par.appendChild(t3);
tag.appendChild(t2);
par.appendChild(tag);
note.parentElement.appendChild(par);
```

Here is the HTML code i want to target and is the first table that occurs:

```
<table width="100%" height="15%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="images/banner_bg3.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align=left>&nbsp;
        <img src="images/vit_logo6.jpg" height="76" width="297">
    </td>
    <td align=center>
        <br>
        <font size=5 color=#FFFFFF face="Comic Sans MS">
        <b>V-TOP</b><br>Student Login
        </font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just want to point out: `face="Comic Sans MS"`

Comment: @Xan do you mean about the styling of the link i provided, yes it really sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target the first `table`, then this would likely give you the desired result

```
var note = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

If the `table` is not the first element in its parent, you need to use `insertBefore` instead of `appendChild`

```
note.parentElement.insertBefore(par, note);
```

*Side note:*

If the `table:nth-child(1) { display: none; }` won't work, you could use `replaceChild` to replace the `table` with your new element

```
note.parentElement.replaceChild(par, note);
```

or simply remove it

```
note.parentElement.removeChild(note);
```

Note though, that if you are to remove it, do that after you inserted the new, or else there will be no reference where to insert the new.

If you still need to remove before add, read more here how to get the element to be removed's next sibling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: and i how can i add a navbar after targeting it?

Comment: @rahulkapoor Doesn't your sample code work now? ... and gets injected

Comment: it gets injected at the end of the page, you know why?

Comment: @rahulkapoor Then your `table` might not be the first element. Updated my answer how to do if that is the case. If it still doesn't work, you need to add more of your html markup, so we can see the whole structure.

Comment: thanks! that worked but there is an background image specified in body tag as well as in it's style and i can't seem to remove it can you help me with this. here is how it looks right now : https://i.imgur.com/3nzFJzB.png

Comment: @rahulkapoor Can't you just do `body { background-image: none; }` ? ... if your CSS comes after the default, or an inline style is used, do like this `body { background-image: none !important; }`

Comment: oh..WOW! thanks LGSon, i really appreciate your help.